# flutter_libserialport: SerialPortError: Resource busy, errno = 16

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a desktop program for mac and windows which will communicate with various devices with serial port communication. The program is written in Flutter with `libserialport`. In the beginning everything worked fine and the connections worked perfectly.

Now, `flutter_libserialport` won't read or write to serialports on mac, but they appear in available ports. It has worked in the past, but now I get the same error with all available ports. However, it works to read and write to the same ports with python. I am quite sure that my code works, because it runs on my friends mac. I am using an intel macbook pro 2019.
Thanks in advance.

The error I get for all ports is:

```
SerialPortError Resource busy, errno = 16.
```

However, I can't see how my ports are busy.